# gitコマンドでファイル削除されることはありますか？

Tags: git, git-bash

gitコマンドは、「.git」フォルダ内だけを操作すると思ったのですが、そうではないのですか？
ファイル削除されることはありますか？

環境
Windows
Git Bash

---

作業履歴
まだ一度もコミットしていない状態です。リモートリポジトリはこれから作成する予定でした。

```
$ git add -A
warning: adding embedded git repository: example.com
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint:
hint:   git submodule add <url> example.com
hint:
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint:
hint:   git rm --cached example.com
hint:
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
```

中に別のgitリポジトリがあると表示されたので、そのリポジトリを一旦削除後、再度「$ git add -A」したかったのですが、
(一旦元へ戻そうと思い)下記コマンドを打ったりしている内に、いつの間にかファイルが(意図せず)削除されてしまいました。

```
$ git reset HEAD
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

$ git reset --hard
warning: unable to rmdir 'example.com': Directory not empty
```

この場合どうすれば良かったのですか？
「.git」フォルダを手動で削除して、再度「$ git add -A」？

Comment: 「中に別のgitリポジトリがあると表示されたので、そのリポジトリを一旦削除後」が曖昧なのですけれど rm -Rf example.com したという理解でいいのでしょうか?

Comment: 中にある別のgitリポジトリがない状態で、再度「$ git add -A」したいという意味です。

Comment: 了解です。係り受けを読み間違いました。
『そのリポジトリを一旦削除後、再度「$ git add -A」』したかったと書いてあるのですね。

『そのリポジトリを一旦削除』（する作業をなにか実際に実行してその）後、再度『「$ git add -A」したかった』と読んでしまいました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git reset --hard`は"gitが管理していないファイル"には手を付けないのですけれど、"gitが管理しているファイルに加えられた変更"や"gitで作業途中の状態"をリセットします。

```
% mkdir project
% cd project
% git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/hoge/project/.git/
% echo a > a
% echo b > b
% ls
a  b
% git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    a
    b

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
% git reset --hard
% ls
a  b
```

ファイル a も b も、Untracked files なので`git reset --hard`してもファイルは消えません。

ですが質問者さんに起こったことはこうではなくて、

```
% mkdir project
% cd project
% git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/hogehoge/project/.git/
% echo a > a
% echo b > b
% ls
a  b
% git add -A
% git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   a
    new file:   b

% git reset --hard
% ls
%
```

と想像します。

`git -A`したことで、ファイルaもbも、`Changes to be committed`に入っています。
「新しいファイルを作成したという履歴」で「次に`git commmit`すれば記録される予定の差分」の扱いになっています。
これを`git reset --hard`すると「新しいファイルを作成したという履歴」が**無かったこと**になってファイルが消えています。

(正確ではないかもしれませんがこんなところかと)

---

ちなみに質問者さんの手元で起こったと想像する手順は以下の通り

```
% mkdir project
% cd project
% git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/hogehoge/project/.git/
% mkdir sub
% cd sub
% echo a > subfile
% git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/hogehoge/project/sub/.git/
% git add subfile
% git commit -am "first commit of sub"
[master (root-commit) d8db7a7] first commit of sub
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 subfile
% cd ..
% echo a > a
% echo b > b
% ls
a  b  sub/
% git add -A
warning: adding embedded git repository: sub
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint:
hint:   git submodule add <url> sub
hint:
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint:
hint:   git rm --cached sub
hint:
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
% git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   a
    new file:   b
    new file:   sub

% git reset --hard
warning: unable to rmdir 'sub': Directory not empty
% ls
sub/
```

Comment: なるほど。「git reset」実行する場合は、事前に「git status」実行しておくことで、今どういう状態なのか(「git reset」実行するとどうなるか)、確認できるわけですね。

Answer (score 2):

`git reset` は任意のコミットの状態に戻すコマンドです。例えばファイルを追加した後にそれより以前のコミットに戻せば、当然ファイルは削除されます。

今回、あなたはファイルを作成した後に「一度もコミットしないまま」`git reset --hard` を実行しているので、リポジトリに登録されていない(コミットされていない)ファイルが消えた形です。

`.git/` というディレクトリが含まれているとリポジトリとして認識するので、無関係なサブディレクトリは事前に退避 (削除や移動) しておいてから `git add -A` すればよかったのだと思います。

Comment: 「コミット」しても「リモートリポジトリへpush」しても「ローカルの実ファイル」は削除されないけれども、「git reset」すると「ローカルの実ファイル」は削除されることがある、という理解で合っていますか？

Answer (score 0):

よくある説明として、 git が管理しているディレクトリ構造は、 「Working Tree」「Index」「Commit」があるかな、と思っています。

「Working Tree」 --(add)--> Index --(commit)--> Commit

というふうにファイル・ディレクトリは管理されていきます。

さて、この git が管理しているのは「Working Tree」「Index」「Commit」と言いましたが、それが保持されているのは物理的なファイルです。

- Working Tree -- `.git` ディレクトリ以外の全て
- Index/Commit -- `.git` ディレクトリ内部にて管理

そして、 git はバージョン管理ツールなので、 Working Tree に対しても普通にファイルの作成・削除・置換を行います。これができないと、「古いバージョンを Working Tree に checkout」などができないからです。

`git reset --hard` は、指定されたコミット(コミットへの参照が省略された場合には、 HEAD すなわち current branch の先頭)の内容を Working Tree へ反映するコマンドです。(その実、もうちょっと多くのことをやっていて、 Index を指定されてコミットのそれへと一致させる効果もあります。)

Comment: 「$ git add -A」「$ git commit」「$ git push -u origin master」しても、「ローカルの実ファイル」は(見た目上は)そのままなのですが、何か変更されているのですか？　.git/ ディレクトリだけに対する処理だと認識していたのですが…